# ASP.NET Web API Unit Testing : Control database identity increase

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, integration-testing

I have one API project created using ASP.NET Web API 2.0. At the back end I've used SQL database for storage. There is one API which is inserting record in one table, let's call that table as 'X'. I've also created one *API client* to facilitate interaction with API. Now I am writing integration tests for this *API client*.

***Problem:***

Integration tests will run several times daily and if any test fails, email notification will be sent to admin. Table 'X' has identity set for it's primary key, thus for every insert, identity is going to increase. So if integration test for insert API is running continuously, this identity will increase with overwhelming rate. I can delete entries created by tests, but how can I control unwanted increase in identity caused due to integration tests?

Comment: After deleting the records, you can simply reseed it like DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[TestTable]', RESEED, 0);

Comment: @PSK RESEED will start from 0. What will happen to existing records.?

Comment: I use clean database for each run. The test project creates it from scratch each time it starts. If you happen to have multiple instances of the tests running at the same time, eg. multiple branches tested in parallel, then you just create your connection string on the run. If needed the database can be seeded each time, but I prefer that each test prepares it's own dataset that tests are running against. You can avoid conflicts between different scenarios this way.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @yoger. Unfortunately I cannot go this way because API has no way to know whether unit testing invoked it or actual application invoked it.

Comment: You only said you will be deleting the exiting records. And if record exists what is the issue?

Comment: *API has no way to know whether unit testing invoked it* - In that case you should have a separate API for test purposes. Everything that could possibly send out a real email or touch production data should be faked or duplicated for your test scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was finding solution for is not a problem actually. The range of *int* in sql is -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647). My integration tests are never going to exceed this limit. So I don't have to worry about increase due to identity.